# How to use date functions as subquery?

Tags: sql, postgresql, date

I'd like to use

```
SELECT EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM TIMESTAMP '2019-06-01 00:00:00');
```

which works as a standalone query:

```
postgres=# SELECT EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM TIMESTAMP '2019-06-01 00:00:00');
 date_part
------------
 1559347200
(1 row)
```

in a subquery like so:

```
CREATE TABLE events_201906 PARTITION OF events
    FOR VALUES FROM (SELECT EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM TIMESTAMP '2019-06-01 00:00:00')) TO (SELECT EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM TIMESTAMP '2019-07-01 00:00:00'));
```

but I keep getting:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "SELECT"
LINE 2:     FOR VALUES FROM (SELECT EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM TIMESTAMP '20...
                             ^
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [Postgres documentation for `CREATE TABLE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/sql-createtable.html):

> *partition_bound_spec* is:
>
> ```
> IN ( { numeric_literal | string_literal | TRUE | FALSE | NULL } [, ...] ) |
> FROM ( { numeric_literal | string_literal | TRUE | FALSE | MINVALUE | MAXVALUE } [, ...] )
>   TO ( { numeric_literal | string_literal | TRUE | FALSE | MINVALUE | MAXVALUE } [, ...] ) | 
> WITH ( MODULUS numeric_literal, REMAINDER numeric_literal )
> ```

So it can't be a subquery, has to be literal.

If you want though, you can execute the partitioning statement dynamically, with something like:

```
create or replace function create_partition() returns int as
$fn$
declare
     p_from bigint;
     p_to bigint;
     query text;
begin
   SELECT EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM TIMESTAMP '2019-06-01 00:00:00') into p_from;
   SELECT EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM TIMESTAMP '2019-07-01 00:00:00') into p_to;

   query := 'CREATE TABLE events_201906 PARTITION OF events
             FOR VALUES FROM (' || p_from || ') TO (' || p_to || ');';

   execute query;

   return 1;

end;
$fn$ language plpgsql;
```

And execute that. Of course you can make it more useful by accepting arguments for partition name and from/to timestamps.

Comment: Alright but I can use something like `SELECT ... INTO var;` and then reuse it in my query?

Comment: No, but you can select into a variable and then execute the `create table` statement dynamically, see my updated answer.